# Why would my mouse pointer change sizes when using Synergy?

Tags: synergy

If I do not start synergy when my PC boots, I do not have this problem.  If I start synergy, after a random amount of time the mouse cursor itself magnifies and looks 3 times its normal size on 1 of my dual monitors.  If I close out of Synergy the issue does not correct itself, but again, if I never start Synergy, I do not have the issue at all.

I recently upgraded to Win7 from WinXP and still have the same issue, but now instead of always occurring on the right monitor, it sometimes occurs on the left.  If you are not bum-fuzzled enough yet, I have a screen video capture application that when recording, shows the mouse normal on both screens.  I am absolutely at a loss...

I was running Synergy+ before the upgrade, not sure on the version.  I am now running Synergy 1.4.2 beta.

Here is my setup just to clarify

Windows 7 Pro PC with dual monitors Synergy 1.4.2 beta to the left of a Windows XP Pro single monitor running Synergy 1.4.2 beta.

Answer (score 2):

A good first step is to uninstall and reinstall synergy.

Answer (score 2):

Synergy doesn't do anything with the mouse cursor other than hiding it when the mouse is on another screen.  Having the cursor change size sounds like a bug in your video card drivers - if you're already using the latest drivers try an old version to see if there's any difference.